# Why am I getting this error in the conftest - ImportError while loading conftest

Tags: python, authentication, conftest

Following is the error I am getting in command Prompt:

```
ImportError while loading conftest 'C:\Users\skatore\PycharmProjects\pythonProjectAgilityFairs\tests\conftest.py'.

conftest.py:12: in <module>

    class Testconf1:

conftest.py:50: in Testconf1

    ???

E   TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Could you please add that import statement in the post?

Comment: Please add those codes that are related to this error..